# Why does hibernate demand a default constructor for java.lang.Double?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa

I'm using JPA and Hibernate as a provider, I want to map a `Map<Embeddable, Double>` with [@ElementCollection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html), but when persisiting, I got an hibernate exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: java.lang.Double
```

I know that :

> if the values of the Map are either embeddable or basic types, the Map
>   is mapped as an element collection. [**Pro JPA 2 *Second edition*- Page 102**]

So in my case I should use @ElementCollection, but why does hibernate consider Double as an entity and demand a default constructor ?

Hibernate/JPA dependencies:

```
    <properties>        
        <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
  ....
  <dependencies>
```

My Classes (I'm using generic types with inheritance Single-Table Strategy):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GENERIC_STAFF")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "My_Discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 255)
public class FirstLevelBaseClass {  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }   
}

 @Getter @Setter
 public class SecondLevelBaseClass <K extends Serializable, V extends Serializable, M extends Map<K, V>> extends FirstLevelBaseClass{
     private M value;
 }

@Entity // Class that I want to persist
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "My_DoubleMapClass")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class DoubleMapClass extends SecondLevelBaseClass<EmbeddableDate, Double, SortedMap<EmbeddableDate, Double>>{

    @Override
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_GENERIC"))
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "key.start", column = @Column(name = "START")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "key.end", column = @Column(name = "END"))
    })
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "MyValue")
    @OrderBy    
    public SortedMap<EmbeddableDate, Double> getValue() {
        return super.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(SortedMap<EmbeddableDate, Double> value) {
        super.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're *treating* it like an entity here.  It's very, very unclear what you're trying to accomplish by placing generics on your entities.

Comment: Just to give more insight, I've another entity that extends from `SecondLevelBaseClass` but with `SortedMap<Integer, Integer>`  and I can persist it wihtout any problem!

Comment: This looks like a bug in Hibernate. Have you tried narrowing down the source of the problem (e.g. removing `@AttributeOverride`, `@Column` etc. to see if you can find a version that works)? Note that you cannot use `nullable=false` with single-table inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [crizzis mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393507/why-does-hibernate-demand-a-default-constructor-for-java-lang-double#comment75787820_44393507), when I get rid of `@AttributeOverride`, I can persist without any exception (It seems like a bug in Hibernate), so to keep my ability to override both the key and value column name, I've created a wrapper class of Double as [@Embeddable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html), so my collection becomes `SortedMap<EmbeddableDate, EmbeddableDouble>`.

the other solution is to not override `EmbeddableDate` field at all and name their columns directly in `EmbeddableDate`, but it wasn't possible for my case, as I'm using `EmbeddableDate` in other entities (and I will lose its reusability!!).